The maximal orders of Hamilton Quaternion Algebras?
Let $\mathbb{H}=\left(\dfrac{-1,-1}{\mathbb{Q}}\right)$ the quaternion algebra described as usual.
$\mathbb{H}=\{x_0+x_1i+x_2j+x_3ij|i=j=-1,ij=-ji\}$ and we can assume k=ij for convenience.
I know, for example, that the subset $Z=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}i+\mathbb{Z}j+\mathbb{Z}k$ define a order, but i think that is not maximal, cause we can describe the set $\dfrac{Z}{2}=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{2}+\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{2}i+\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{2}j+\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{2}k$
Update: One maximal order is $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}i+\mathbb{Z}j+\mathbb{Z}\left(\dfrac{-1+i+j+k}{2}\right)$.
The proof of maximal can be looked at "The Arithmetic of Quaternion Algebras - John Voight", to proof it is in fact a order is not difficult.
Now my question is: Is that the unique maximal order of $\mathbb{H}$?
Obs: Please, my english isn't that good, so if someone can correct, i'll be gratefull.

Suggestion: look at Conway and Smith's book on quaternions and octonions.

Ok, i'll see here. Thanks!

No. The order you described is maximal, but maximal orders are not unique. If $\mathcal{B}=\{\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2,\mathbf{u}_3\}$ is any right handed orthonormal system of vectors in $\Bbb{Q}^3$, then you get a similar maximal order
$$
\Lambda_{\mathcal{B}}=\{a_1\mathbf{u}_1+a_2\mathbf{u}_2+a_3\mathbf{u}_3+
a_4\frac{\left(-1+\mathbf{u}_1+\mathbf{u}_2+\mathbf{u}_3\right)}2\mid a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\in\Bbb{Z}\}.
$$
All of those work because the multiplication of quaternions is based on the usual inner as well as cross products of 3D-vectors. Here $\mathbf{u}_1\times \mathbf{u}_2=\mathbf{u}_3$ with the usual cyclic shifts.
For example, we can use $\mathbf{u}_1=(3\mathbf{i}+4\mathbf{j})/5$, $\mathbf{u}_2=\mathbf{k}$, and $\mathbf{u}_3=\mathbf{u}_1\times \mathbf{u}_2=(-3\mathbf{j}+4\mathbf{i})/5$. Clearly $\mathbf{u}_1\notin\Lambda_{\{\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}\}}$, so the two maximal orders are different.

OTOH all the maximal orders of any quaternion algebra (of any division algebra with center $\Bbb{Q}$) have "the same size" (=share the same discriminant). That is, if $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ are two maximal orders, then their intersection $\Lambda_1\cap\Lambda_2$ has finite index in both of them, and the indices are equal:
$$
[\Lambda_1:\Lambda_1\cap\Lambda_2]=[\Lambda_2:\Lambda_1\cap\Lambda_2].
$$

IIRC any pair of maximal orders can be linked by a sequence of "moves", where we select a full rank sublattice and consider its left/right orders. I learned such details from Reiner's book. Others may be equally good. I haven't studied this topic from other sources, so cannot make meaningful comparisons.

I think the two maximal orders in my post are each others conjugates. In other words, there is a quaternion $\mathbf{q}$ such that $$\mathbf{q}\Lambda_{{\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}}}\mathbf{q}^{-1}=\Lambda_{\mathcal{B}}.$$ It may be that in the case of (rational) Hamilton's quaternion algebra all the maximal orders are conjugate. I don't have a recollection about this :-(

Oh, very well, thank you. Maybe (in this case) it's the same of maximal orders of $M_2(\mathbb(Q)$. I'll investigate this. In any case, it's be clear that is not unique. Thank you so much.
